# Is there a better way to use beautiful soup to scrape data buried deep in an html file?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a personal project that scrapes my university's dining hall menu and returns the daily dessert menu for the upcoming week.  I am using beautiful soup to do this, but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly because my code seems indirect and repetitive.  Is there a way to essentially jump all the way to my last line without the intermediate steps? Here is what I currently have:

```
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
for column in soup.find_all('div', class_='menu-details-day'): # Looks at the menu for each day
    for station in column.find_all('div',class_='menu-details-station'): # Looks at each station
        if station.h4.string == 'Dessert' :
            for item in station.find_all('div',class_='menu-name'): # Looks at each item served at the dessert station
                # append items to list
```

Just to clarify my expected output, I am attempting to get each dessert item for a single day, which I then append to a list corresponding to that day.  Here is one of the [links](https://virginia.campusdish.com/Commerce/Catalog/Menus.aspx?LocationId=701&PeriodId=&MenuDate=&Mode=week) I am scraping from.

Comment: if lxml is an option then I would use that instead and use its xpath functionality, its easier and straightforward

Answer (score 1):

if you want a better way because dont want arrow code, you could use itertools to make this logic into a generator pipeline

```
from itertools import chain

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

# extract all stations for each day
stations = chain(*(
    col.find_all('div',class_='menu-details-station') 
    for col in soup.find_all('div', class_='menu-details-day')
))
desserts = chain(*(
    station.find_all('div',class_='menu-name') 
    for station in stations
    if station.h4.string == 'Dessert'
))

for dessert in desserts:
    print(dessert)
```